# Unable to write a csv file in spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a csv file using spark 1.6.1.
Say I have a csv file like this:

```
date,category
19900108,apples
19900108,apples
19900308,peaches
19900408,peaches
19900508,pears
19910108,pears
19910108,peaches
19910308,apples
19910408,apples
19910508,apples
19920108,pears
19920108,peaches
19920308,apples
19920408,peaches
19920508,pears
```

I want to create an output csv file like this:

```
date,apples,peaches,pears
1990,2,2,1
1991,3,1,1
1992,1,2,2
```

I am using this scala code to load the file:

```
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

var df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("data/sample.csv")

df = df.withColumn("year", df.col("date").substr(0,4)) 
df.groupBy("year").pivot("category").agg("category"->"count").show()
```

When I run this I get this dataframe which is exactly what I want

```
+----+------+-------+-----+
|year|apples|peaches|pears|
+----+------+-------+-----+
|1990|     2|      2|    1|
|1991|     3|      1|    1|
|1992|     1|      2|    2|
+----+------+-------+-----+
```

But when I try to write this to a CSV using this code:

```
 df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("mydata4.csv")
```

This is the csv file I am getting when I open it, which is not what I am looking for.

```
date,category,year
19900108,apples,1990
19900108,apples,1990
19900308,peaches,1990
19900408,peaches,1990
19900508,pears,1990
19910108,pears,1991
19910108,peaches,1991
19910308,apples,1991
19910408,apples,1991
19910508,apples,1991
19920108,pears,1992
19920108,peaches,1992
19920308,apples,1992
19920408,peaches,1992
19920508,pears,1992
```

Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to store the result of your query into a new variable.

```
val xf = df.groupBy("year").pivot("category").agg("category"->"count")
```

and then write it using your last code line.

```
xf.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("mydata4.csv")
```